# MySQL Stored Procedure Processing String Array

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, stored-functions

**Data Set:**

I have data that stored tags into an array of Strings:

```
+-----+-----------------------------------+
| Id  |  Tag                              |
+-----+-----------------------------------+
| 1   |  ["cafe","bar","tapas"]           |
+-----+-----------------------------------+
| 2   |  ["cafe","bar", "sandwiches"]     |
+-----+-----------------------------------+
```

I'd like to compare the tags for ID = 1 against tags for ID = 2 via MySQL
I was looking at creating a stored procedure for it but can't find any text processing features in MySQL.

**End Result:**

```
+-------------------+
| Tag               |
+-------------------+
| "cafe"            |
+-------------------+
| "bar"             |
+-------------------+
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should redesign the table. There should be a tag table and another is tagList table which has the relationship of of tag table.

Comment: Hi Sarwar026. Thanks for that. I have no control over the table format. I'm data munging from an external source.
Just finding some creative ways to work with what I have.
Trying to use Java to do the processing in the meantime.

Comment: It's ok. Just to share my idea! Thanks

Comment: One option that may help is to use the framework [common_schema](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html), specifically [text_routines](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/text_routines.html).